# Angular Toggle Function is not sustained on page refresh

Tags: angularjs, toggle

In Angular  have a toggle function that works as expected but as the page refreshes the toggle state is not sustained

Objective : Sustain Toggle State on page refresh

```
  $scope.toggle = !$scope.toggle;

    $scope.$watch('toggle', function(){

    $scope.toggleText = $scope.toggle ? 'Guess The Year!' : 'Reveal The   Year';
})



   //HTML


 <div> ng-show="toggle">Reveal </div>

   <div> ng-hide="toggle">Hide </div>
```

Comment: In Angular when you refresh the page all variables are back to default, unless you save it in `localStorage` and load it

Comment: Every time you refresh the page the angular app is re-initialized so no surprises that state is not restored. You need to use some persistence technique (i.e. local storage) to save/restore the state on page refresh.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should go with local storage to overcome this problem

Here is some code it may help you

```
().controller('asdad', [function() {
    //default setting
    $scope.toggle = localStorage.toggle !== undefined ? JSON.parse(localStorage.toggle) : YourDefaultValue;

    //change state function
    $scope.stateFun = function() {
        $scope.toggle = !$scope.toggle;

        $scope.$watch('toggle', function(){
            localStorage.toggle = $scope.toggle; 
            $scope.toggleText = $scope.toggle ? 'Guess The Year!' : 'Reveal The   Year';
        })        
    };  
}]);
```

Answer (score -1):

On refresh of the page the controller is called again and hence all the scope variables are also initialised again.
If you want to sustain its value place value in localStorage.

Comment: $rootScope is also reinitialized and not persisted on page refresh